# How to remove an apt package?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, package-management, update-manager

Hello i'd like to know how to remove 2 apt things that gets an error any time I type `apt-get update` here is the output at the end

`W: Failed to fetch https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo-for-Linux/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo-for-Linux/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404
`
I've already tried ppa purge and apt remove neither worked.

Comment: inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ resides your sources lists just remove the line with gyazo github

Comment: Please do not put answers inside the question and add "[Solved]" to the title. There is a text window marked "Your Answer" below. You can answer your own question there and accept it as correct.

Comment: I solved this by going into /etc/apt/sources.list and taking out both of the github links.